# How to run javascript using server side code in ASP.Net Web Form application in update panel?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to use some javascript code inside update panel in ASP.Net web form application using serverside code. The problem is the following code only works if i used it outside update panel but not works inside, even with alert.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Server" OnClick="Button1_Click"/><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Cleint" OnClientClick="alert('Hello World(Cleint)')"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
            "ShowMessage", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>",
            "Hello World (Server)"));
    }
```

when running this application only the Client Click event works but not the server side event. However when removing update panel ant try again both events work.
I searched a lot and found some similar questions but all answers didn't work. I just wanna to fix problem for the example i put above. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace your code behind in the button click event with this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), this.ClientID, string.Format("alert('{0}')", "Server"), true);
```

Hope this helps.